# Is there a word for the value of a complex number multiplied by its conjugate?

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology

For a complex number $w$, or $a+bi$, is there a specific term for the value $w\overline{w}$, or $a^2+b^2$?

Comment: Square of the modulus , i.e., $|a+bi|^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Gaussian integer, I've seen this called the norm, for example here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/Zinotes.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Not for $w\bar{w}$, but for its square root there is:
$$
|\,w\,| =\sqrt{w\bar{w}} = \mbox{ magnitude of $w$}
$$